# How to refresh data without page reloading in Asp.net core MVC using Ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have data filtering using a checkbox. I want that when I click on the "Submit" button, only the products are updated without reloading the page

Here's the filtering:

```
<form id="my_form" asp-action="Face" method="get">
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="black" /><span>Black</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="white" /><span>White</span>
    <br />
    <p></p>
    <label>Manufacturer:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="B" /><span>B</span>
    <input class="btn btn-info float-right" type="submit" value="Search" />
    //Etc
</form>
```

I need this data to be displayed first. And in the case of passing filters, they were updated depending on what I passed to the controller

```
 <div class="row pr-3 pl-3">
            @foreach (var c in Model)
            {
                <div class="filter col-md-3 p-0 hover-bc-card" data-category="@c.PurposeFor">
                    <div class="p-3">
                        <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" asp-action="Product" asp-controller="Cosmetic" asp-route-id="@c.Id">
                            <div>
                                <img class="card-img-top p-4 bg-white" src=@c.Img alt="@c.Name">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title text-center">@c.Name</h5>
                            <p class="card-text text-center f-sz-12 ">@c.PurposeFor</p>
                            <p class="card-text rounded text-center price-for-list">@c.Price ₴</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Just in case my controller:

```
public IActionResult Face(string[] color, string[] brand, string[] PurposeFor, string sortOrder)
    {

        ViewBag.color = color;
        ViewBag.PurposeFor = PurposeFor;
        ViewBag.brand = brand;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "Price_desc" : "Price";

        var cosmetics = db.Cosmetics.Where(c => c.PurposeFor.Contains("Face")).ToList();
        var co_cars = new List<Cosmetic>();
        var ma_cars = new List<Cosmetic>();
        var purposeFor = new List<Cosmetic>();


        if (color.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (string co in color)
            {
                var colorfiltercars = db.Cosmetics.Where(c => c.Color.Contains(co)).ToList();
                co_cars.AddRange(colorfiltercars);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            co_cars = cosmetics;
        }

        if (PurposeFor.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (string pf in PurposeFor)
            {
                var purposefiltercars = db.Cosmetics.Where(c => c.PurposeFor.Contains(pf)).ToList();
                purposeFor.AddRange(purposefiltercars);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            purposeFor = cosmetics;
        }

        if (brand.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (string ma in brand)
            {
                var manufacturerfiltercars = db.Cosmetics.Where(c => c.Brand.Contains(ma)).ToList();
                ma_cars.AddRange(manufacturerfiltercars);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ma_cars = cosmetics;
        }

        var filtercars = co_cars.Intersect(ma_cars);
        filtercars = filtercars.Intersect(purposeFor);

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name_desc":
                filtercars = filtercars.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
            case "Price":
                filtercars = filtercars.OrderBy(s => s.Price);
                break;
            case "Price_desc":
                filtercars = filtercars.OrderByDescending(s => s.Price);
                break;
            default:
                filtercars = filtercars.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                break;
        }
        return View(filtercars.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: What is the specific issue that you are facing while making an ajax call?

Comment: I know how to call ajax but don't know how to use it with mvc. I can make a call button that will work with ajax and html, but I could not find how to combine all this with mvc.

Comment: More precisely, I found how to use it in mvc. But that wouldn't help my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want that when I click on the "Submit" button, only the products are updated without reloading the page

You can refer to the following code snippet to [perform AJAX submission using jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax) and dynamically update the target container with returned partial view result.

```
<form id="my_form" asp-action="Face" method="get" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="get" data-ajax-update="#panel" data-ajax-mode='replace' data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("GetPartial","Home")">
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="black" /><span>Black</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="white" /><span>White</span>
    <br />
    <p></p>
    <label>Manufacturer:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="B" /><span>B</span>
    <input class="btn btn-info float-right" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

*Add reference to jquery-ajax-unobtrusive*

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

*Specify `id` attribute `panel` to div container*

```
<div class="row pr-3 pl-3" id="panel">
```

*Action method that returns a partial view*

```
public IActionResult GetPartial(string[] color, string[] brand, string[] PurposeFor, string sortOrder)
{
    //move your query code logic in custom method GetFilterData
    var filtercars = GetFilterData(color, brand, PurposeFor, sortOrder);

    return PartialView("_CarListPartial", filtercars);
}
```

*Partial view _CarListPartial.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<WebNaApp.Models.Cosmetic>

@foreach (var c in Model)
{
    <div class="filter col-md-3 p-0 hover-bc-card" data-category="@c.PurposeFor">
        <div class="p-3">
            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" asp-action="Product" asp-controller="Cosmetic" asp-route-id="@c.Id">
                <div>
                    <img class="card-img-top p-4 bg-white" src=@c.Img alt="@c.Name">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">@c.Name</h5>
                <p class="card-text text-center f-sz-12 ">@c.PurposeFor</p>
                <p class="card-text rounded text-center price-for-list">@c.Price ₴</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: You can also achieve same using jQuery Ajax by loading returned partial view result in target div container in Ajax success callback function.

Comment: This looks like what I need. But I definitely need the request to be passed to the query string. So that I can copy the link and send to others with filters applied

Comment: `I definitely need the request to be passed to the query string. So that I can copy the link and send to others with filters applied` Hi @Betsq9, to achieve this requirement, as I mentioned in comment you can achieve same by making jQuery Ajax to `GetPartial` action, then load/append returned partial view result in target div container.

Comment: Besides, if you check the actual request in F12 developer tool Network tab, you would find that the above code using jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX is also passing data through query string.

Comment: @FeiHan But what if we need not to use JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following step if you want to avoid page reload :

1- JQuery and Ajax Post to send data to controller

2- Function in your controller to manage the data and send a response with the data you need

3- In the success part of your Ajax .clear or .append the HTML part concerned like a div or select option

here is a little example to guide you, but you have to adapt it corresponding to your need:

In CSHTML: don't forget to add an Id to your checkbox :

```
<button type="button" onclick="checkMe()">Search</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" />
<script>
  function checkMe() {
  // here get value of your checkbox1 
  var Checkbox1state = $('#Checkbox1').prop('checked');
  var Checkbox2state = $('#Checkbox2').prop('checked');
  // and some logic how you want to filter if there is many parameter
  var id =0
  if (Checkbox2state) { id=1 } else {  id=2 };
  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Home/AjaxMethodeCheckMe",
      data: '{id: "' + id + '" }',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (ListOfItems) {
        $("#yourDropDown").empty();
        $.each(ListOfItems, function (i, item) {
        $("#yourDropDown").append('<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>');
        });
      },
      failure: function (response) {
        alert("failure");
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
      },
    });
  }
  
</script>
```

in your controller:

```
public JsonResult AjaxMethodeCheckMe(int id)
{
    List<SelectListItem> ListOfPort = new List<SelectListItem>();

    ListOfPort.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text 1", Value = "Value1" });
    ListOfPort.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text 2", Value = "Value2" });
    ListOfPort.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text 3", Value = "Value3" });

    return Json(new SelectList(ListOfPort, "Value", "Text"));
}
```

Here i show how to do with dropdown but you can modify ...