# Add row to table using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I create a functionality consisting of adding ingredients from
Ingredients' table to 'Recipes' table of recipes. I created the viemodel "RecipesVM" where there are list objects from "Ingredients" and "Recipes" tables. I made a method that displays these lists in the view using the "foreach" loop. Additionally I gave a button next to each record in "IngredientsVM" list to add an assigned row to "RecipeVM" list.
Only how can I add this line using controller and ajax, so that it does not refresh my page every time it adds line to "RecipeVM" list
Please help me
Thank you

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Frykas.Data.Models;
using Frykas.Data.Services;
using Frykas.Web.ViewModels;

namespace Frykas.Web.Controllers
{
    public class RecipesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Recipes
        public ActionResult CreateRecipe(int IdProduct)
        {
            FrykasDbContext frykasDb = new FrykasDbContext();
            RecipesVM recipesvm = new RecipesVM();
            recipesvm.RecipeVM = new List<Recipes>();
            var recipelist = frykasDb.Recipes.ToList();
            foreach(var item in recipelist)
            {
                Recipes objrecvm = new Recipes();
                objrecvm.IdRecipe = item.IdRecipe;
                objrecvm.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                recipesvm.RecipeVM.Add(objrecvm);
            }

            recipesvm.IngredientsVM = new List<Ingredients>();
            var ingredientslist = frykasDb.Ingredients.ToList();
            foreach(var item in ingredientslist)
            {
                Ingredients objingvm = new Ingredients();
                objingvm.Id = item.Id;
                objingvm.Name = item.Name;
                recipesvm.IngredientsVM.Add(objingvm);
            }
            
            return View(recipesvm);
        }

        public ActionResult AddIngredient()
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**VieModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Frykas.Web;
using Frykas.Data.Models;
using Frykas.Data.Services;


namespace Frykas.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class RecipesVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Recipes> RecipeVM { get; set; }

        public List<Ingredients> IngredientsVM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
    </div>
    <h4>Składniki receptury</h4>
    <table class="table">
        @foreach (var itemrec in Model.RecipeVM)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => itemrec.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => itemrec.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => itemrec.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => itemrec.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <h4>Składniki</h4>
    <table class="table">
        @foreach (var iteming in Model.IngredientsVM)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => iteming.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input value="Dodaj" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Stwórz" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two methods that can achieve your target:

**A)** You can use jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX, with loading a partial view.
There is a good tutorial that you can follow here (Asp .net Core) : [Using jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX in ASP.NET](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax)

**B)** Use AJAX response to append an HTML DIV :
Here I answered to a similar question, please check : [How to refresh data without page reloading in Asp.net core MVC using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65379758/14718192)

If you need more help, let me know to Edit.